# Why doesn't clang++ compile the same file as g++ do?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
struct foo {};

template<std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class bar {
public:
    bar(const foo<R, C>& = foo<R, C>()) {}
};

int main() {
    bar<10, 10> y;
    std::cout << 'x';
}
```

The above code [compiles and runs correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb69fa82ee02a882) (printing `x` as output) on g++ v4.8, while the same [does not even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bce457857c250621) on clang++ v3.4, claiming an `error: unknown type name 'C'`. Why does the compilation's result differ between the two versions?

The commands used for compilation are:

```
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
clang++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

Comment: At the very least you should include the header where `std::size_t` is defined.

Comment: @juanchopanza, absolutely true, fixed. (the problem of course is still there)

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug

Comment: FWIW, with a type alias Clang [happily compiles it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/013b6cc48a11dd81).

Comment: This is definitly a bug in Clang. As a work-around, try `= (foo<R,C>())` - the parser seems to think that the `,` there seperates the parameter list. It also appears to be fixed higher in the trunk, at least on r191604.

Comment: Appears to be fixed in tip-of-trunk clang.

Comment: Please include the error message in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a defect in the Standard, handled as http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#325 .

The problem is that name lookup in default arguments within classes should consider all class members (including the class members declared later), but when the default argument is `T<X, Y>`, we only know what the default argument is once we have completely parsed the class (the default argument could be `T<X, Y>` or could be `T<X`, with the comma terminating the default argument if `T` is not a template in the complete scope of the class).

In working around this problem, GCC and Clang apparently take differnet approaches on this. You can simply fix your code by parenthesizing your default argument.